# Analysing multiple .csv imported in R

Tags: r, csv

Im importing 3 sets of data into R which is a .csv file using

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="C:/120315.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
MyData2 <- read.csv(file="C:/120415.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
MyData3 <- read.csv(file="C:/120515.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

The format of my raw data for the .csv file is as below. "Last" would be the "Close" of each stock market price.

```
"Stock","Open","High","Low","Last","Vol"
"ABCD",".490","8.550","8.350","8.350","101,500"
"ASDFG","11.800","11.800","11.570","11.700","110,900"
"XCVXCV","22.430","22.600","22.340","22.600","9,314,100"
"BCVBCVB","4.380","4.390","4.380","4.390","122,000"
"FSDFSDF","8.850","8.850","8.850","8.850","200"
```

How would I use R to analyse those 3 .csv files, to list out the Stocks that have 2 consecutive days of price increases?

Meaning, the "Last" would have increased in 2 consecutive days (e.g. 1st day - 5.5, 2nd day - 5.8, 3rd day - 5.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice way to do it using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

file_names <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

read_file <- function(file) {
  df <- read.csv(file)
  df$day <- as.Date(file, '%m%d%y')
  df
}

file_names %>% 
  lapply(read_file) %>%
  rbind_all() %>% 
  group_by(Stock) %>% 
  mutate(
    two_in_a_row = Last > lag(Last, 2, order_by = day) & Last > lag(Last, 1, order_by = day)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
mydata1 <- read.csv(header=T, text='"Stock","Open","High","Low","Last","Vol"
"ABCD",".490","8.550","8.350","8.350","101,500"')
mydata2 <- read.csv(header=T, text='"Stock","Open","High","Low","Last","Vol"
"ABCD",".490","8.550","8.350","9.350","101,500"')
mydata3 <- read.csv(header=T, text='"Stock","Open","High","Low","Last","Vol"
"ABCD",".490","8.550","8.350","10.350","101,500"')
mydata4 <- read.csv(header=T, text='"Stock","Open","High","Low","Last","Vol"
"ABCD",".490","8.550","8.350","1.350","101,500"')

(mydata <- do.call(rbind, mget(grep("^mydata\\d+", ls(), val=T))))
#         Stock Open High  Low  Last     Vol
# mydata1  ABCD 0.49 8.55 8.35  8.35 101,500
# mydata2  ABCD 0.49 8.55 8.35  9.35 101,500
# mydata3  ABCD 0.49 8.55 8.35 10.35 101,500
# mydata4  ABCD 0.49 8.55 8.35  1.35 101,500

lapply(split(mydata, mydata$Stock), function(df) {
  with(rle(diff(df$Last) > 0), any(lengths[values==TRUE] >= 2)) # increased 2 consecutive days?
})
# $ABCD
# [1] TRUE
```